# Enabling Macro Keys of Alienware 17R4 and utilizing them on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: keyboard, alienware

So I have an Alienware 17R4 that has 6 Macrokeys on the left side named: x,1,2,3,4,5
and 4 macrokeys on top of the keypad to the right side named: 6,7,8,9
On windows I can use the x macrokey to toggle macrokeys numbered 1 through 5 between three different modes. So basically there are 15 macrokeys instead of 5.
My question is how can I do the same on Ubuntu?

**Things Worth mentioning:**

Using the command  `showkey`  I cannot even get a scancode for the macrokeys when I press them. Also in the output of  `xmodmap -pke` there are some empty lines for certain keys which makes my assumption correct. So ***how can I enable them?*** Because once they are enabled, I can use their scan code to assign macros to them. Also **_How can I use the x macrokey to toggle their modes?**

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem on my AW15R3 and solved it

first install the following packages on ubuntu

```
sudo apt install  ghc libusb-1.0-0-dev cabal-install git pkg-config python-usb -y
```

then get the scan code of each key from the following command:

```
dmesg | grep -i code
```

for example when I press the macro key 4 the following message is printed that indicate the scancode is `e015`

```
[ 1737.342249] atkbd serio0: Unknown key released (translated set 2, code 0x95 on isa0060/serio0).
```

Now the "e015" is the scan code and you need to map that to a free keycode in the system. This could happen by running `sudo setkeycodes e011 204`
so create a script under `/etc/init.d` to map the scan codes to a free keycodes available for all keys.

Please note that you need to execute the below commands on Linux console not on the x-server (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to switch to Linux console from X). Use `sudo vim /etc/init.d/keyremap` and
map the codes to the keycodes:

```
sudo setkeycodes e011 146
sudo setkeycodes e012 148
sudo setkeycodes e013 149
sudo setkeycodes e014 203
sudo setkeycodes e015 204
sudo setkeycodes e016 184
```

Then make the script executable by `chmod +x keyremap`

Finally use `xmodmap` utility to map the keycodes to keysym so your Xorg can understand and catch the key events using `vim ~/.Xmodmap`:

```
  keycode 154 = XF86Launch0
  keycode 156 = XF86Launch1
  keycode 157 = XF86Launch2
  keycode 211 = XF86Launch3
  keycode 212 = XF86Launch4
  keycode 172 = XF86Launch5
```

Then run `sudo xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`

Now you can map the `XF86Launchx` to any action by using the keyboard shortcuts:

[image]

You can create an entry in `rc.local` so these scripts are executed automatically when machine boot up.